# Rails returns nil, Postgres returns rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have the following table structure:

[image: Data Model]

In Rails console I execute:

```
@address = Address.first
```

@address.id = 1

Then:

```
    @devices = Address.select("devices.unit, models.name,
       manufacturers.name").joins
      (device_groups: [{ devices: {  model:  :manufacturer}}]).find(@address.id)
```

The result is that @devices is nil.

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT devices.unit, models.name, manufacturers.name FROM "addresses" 
INNER JOIN "device_groups" ON "device_groups"."address" = "addresses"."id" 
INNER JOIN "devices" ON "devices"."group" = "device_groups"."id"
INNER JOIN "models" ON "models"."id" = "devices"."model" 
INNER JOIN "manufacturers" ON "manufacturers"."id" = "models"."manufacturer" 
WHERE "addresses"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I took this SQL and using psql executed the equivalent:

```
SELECT devices.unit, models.name, manufacturers.name FROM "addresses" 
INNER JOIN "device_groups" ON "device_groups"."address" = "addresses"."id" 
INNER JOIN "devices" ON "devices"."group" = "device_groups"."id" 
INNER JOIN "models" ON "models"."id" = "devices"."model" 
INNER JOIN "manufacturers" ON "manufacturers"."id" = "models"."manufacturer"
WHERE "addresses"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

psql returned:

```
 unit | name |       name        
------+------+-------------------
 76   | est  | Sipes-Heidenreich
```

(1 row)

I'm a noob, so can someone enlighten me as to what is causing this divergence of result?
Also why is Rails adding a limit, as I want all device rows that are matched in the joins?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` comes from the `find` which returns only one thing. Are you sure that `psql` and Rails are connecting to the same database?

Comment: Yes, same database.
My question still stands - Rails returns nil, and postgres returns a row. Why?

Comment: ActiveRecord is an ORM -- Object Relational Mapper -- it wants to map the query results into the object specified by model used to call the query.  In your code this is Address. Your query returns NOTHING to use fill an address so you get a nill result. As you are looking for devices -- call the query from the Device model.

Comment: @dbugger: I ran the query output from ActiveRecord using psql and it returned the correct result. So what you are saying is the ActiveRecord executes the correct SQL query, but because the model is Address instead of Device, it throws away the result set?

Comment: Exactly - query the proper object